# Удаление через drag and drop android

Tags: android, java

Как реализовать удаление элементов как в основном меню андроида: зажимаем элемент и перетаскиваем его наверх?
Я пытаюсь такое сделать, но появляется проблема.

У меня есть `ListView`, когда зажимаю на каком-то элементе, появляется фрагмент `RemoveBar` - он отвечает за то, что появляется лэйоут удаления, в котором есть `ImageView`.

```
taskListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("CURR_TEST","itemClickLong");
            dragItem((Task) parent.getItemAtPosition(position),view);

            TaskHolder.getInstance().putTask((Task) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            sendCommand(FactoryCommandFragment.getInstance().getCommand("drag,"+parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)));
            return true;
        }
    });
    taskListView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            Log.d("dragEvent", "event : " + event.getAction());
            Log.d("Bad Listener worked","rrr");
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    draggedItemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
              //  case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
              //     sendCommand(FactoryCommandFragment.getInstance().getCommand("drag_cancel,l"));
                default:
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

У картинки `ImageView` тоже есть `OnDragListener`. когда пользователь опускает элемент над ним. Элемент удаляется.

```
public class RemoveBarFragment extends BarFragment {

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    TopBarFragment topBarFragment;
    private final static String LOG_TAG = "BarFragment/RemoveBarFragment";
    private void init(){

        thisView.findViewById(R.id.removeImageButton).setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "drag_event : " + event.getAction());
                Log.v("check","listener worked");

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        sendCommand(FactoryCommandFragment.getInstance().getCommand("dragged,remove"));
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                        sendCommand(FactoryCommandFragment.getInstance().getCommand("drag_cancel,l"));
                        break;
                    default:
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        thisView.getFocusables(View.FOCUS_UP);
        Log.v("check", "listener set");
        executeCommand(FactoryCommandFragment.getInstance().getTopCommand("top,default"));
        redraw();
    }

    public void redraw(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        thisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remove_bar, container, false);

        init();
        return thisView;

    }

    public void executeCommand(Command command) {
        if (thisView == null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Command suspended");
            SuspendedCommand suspended = new SuspendedCommand();
            suspended.execute(command);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Command executed");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < command.getCount(); i++) {
            String commandString = command.getCommand(i);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "command - " + commandString);
            String delim = "[,]";
            String[] tokens = commandString.split(delim);
            if (tokens.length == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("build commandString[" + i + "] is empty");
            }

            if (tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase("redraw")) {
                if (tokens.length == 1) {
                    redraw();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

По непонятным причинам. Когда первый раз зажимаю элемент и перетаскиваю его на фрагмент удаление, он не удаляется, а удаляется со второго раза. Я проверял через отладчик, смотрел объект `thisView` из класса `RemoveBarFragment`, так вот ему не задается `OnDragListener` с первого раза, а задается только со второго.

Вообщем я тестил, если я первый раз зажму палец на одном из элементов и начну его тянуть, `OnDragListener` не зарегестрируется в `RemoveBarFragment` пока я не отпущу палец. Почему так происходит - непонятно. Как сделать так чтоб с первого раза удаляло?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в `init()` thisView еще не назначено и `== null`

```
public void executeCommand(Command command) {
if (thisView == null) { //true
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Command suspended");
    SuspendedCommand suspended = new SuspendedCommand();
    suspended.execute(command);
```

А `thisView` назначается после отработки `init();`
Думаю в этом дело